# Does the medium have any role to play in determining the electric force between two charges?

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law

I came across a question which states:

> Two identical non-conducting solid spheres of same mass and charge are suspended in air from a
> common point by two non-conducting, massless strings of same length. At equilibrium, the angle
> between the strings is . The spheres are now immersed in a dielectric liquid of density 800 $\frac{kg}{m^3}$ and dielectric constant 21. If the angle between the strings remains the same after the immersion,
> then
>
> (A) electric force between the spheres remains unchanged
>
> (B) electric force between the spheres reduces
>
> (Source IIT JEE Advanced 2020)

In my opinion, the first option should be correct because the electric force between the charged spheres will remain constant and equal to $F = \frac{Q_1Q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}$ $\space$ but the answer given by the organizers is the second option (that is, the B option). Can anybody tell where am I going wrong in this question?

Comment: I also tried to find the answer of the question here : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/582965/does-force-between-two-charges-depend-on-medium/582966#comment1458105_582966 but could not find any satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to deal with forces between objects immersed in a fluid because the electric field can attract the fluid into high field regions and this affects the fluid pressure. To answer  need to compute the full stress tensor which involves both the electric and mechanical forces.  I think that the author (of what sounds like an introductory textbook problem) is blisfully unaware that there is no simple answer to his problem.

Comment: Actually this question came in an exam which is targeted for high school students (class 12th) so is there any satisfactory answer at that level?

Comment: Well the spheres  experience some buoyancy effect which should increase the angle, so the force caused by the charge, which includes the actual elecric force *and* the force cause by the electric-induced pressure gradient reduces.

Answer (score 0):

If the charge distribution remains spherical, the electric displacement vector field created by a charge is $\vec{D}=\frac{Q}{4\pi r^2}\vec{e_r}$ and the electric field $ \vec{E}=\frac{\vec{D}}{\epsilon_0\epsilon_r}=\frac{Q}{4\pi{\epsilon_0\epsilon_rr}^2}\vec{e_r}$

The force on the other charge is therefore divided by $\epsilon_r$