# Does the Coulomb's force depend on the configuration of the medium?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law, dielectric

I know that when two charges are placed in a dielectric medium (say water) then the force between the charges get reduced and the force equation is given by :-

$$F=\frac{q_1q_2}{(4π \epsilon_o \epsilon_r) r^2} $$

**But I want to ask whether this force also depends on the configuration of the charges inside the medium or not i.e. is the force on the charges different in the two cases given in the figure ?**

[image]

**Note :-** The figure is not drawn to scale and assume the distance between the two charges to be same in both the figures. The rectangle represents the region with permittivity $\epsilon_o \epsilon_r$.

Comment: in your figure the distances aren’t the same so *this* will make a difference but otherwise can you clarify why would you think the “configuration” matters?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero i am sorry the figure was not to scale but assume the distance to be the same ... Actually I don't think it matters but was trying to confirm whether it does matter or not !

Comment: I assume that the rectangle in your drawing represents the region where the dielectric constant is $\epsilon_0\epsilon_r$, while outside the rectangle, it is $\epsilon_0$. If this is the case, it would be better to write it explicitly in the question.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/662239/direction-of-electric-field-at-points-on-boundary-between-two-dieletrics

Comment: @Beautifully irrational i did go through Purcell but i couldn't find this thing anywhere.. could you tell me where it is or point it out ?

Comment: I recall dielectrics being discussed in extreme detail in the capacitor chapter. So much so that I gave up reading lol @Ankit but maybe it is not there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the rectangle represents the region occupied by the dielectric, the answer is yes; the force depends not only on the distance between the two charges but also on their distance from the boundary of the dielectric region. The physical reason is that at the border between two media with a different dielectric constant, the presence of each charge induces a bound polarization charge modifying the total electric field.

A quantitative treatment of the problem is not trivial. Basically, it can be obtained by using the method of images. The interaction energy between the two charges can be found [here (formula ($57$)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2399-6528/aaa70a/pdf), although that paper derives the formula in a more general (and complex) way. (Warning: I did not have time to check the correctness of the final formula, but the method is sound). The interesting fact is that the presence of the dielectric boundary with the effect of bound charges can even reverse the sign of the forces.

Comment: so why don't we use any factor in the equation accounting for that ?

Comment: @Ankit because it is a modification dependent on the geometry, i.e., it modifies the $1/r^2$ behavior. It is not a simple constant factor and has to be evaluated case by case.

Comment: Can you expand on why this isn’t baked in the value of $\epsilon$, which captures the effect of bound charges?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero a constant scaling captures the effect of bound charges only in a completely isotropic case. If you refer to the method of image charges, it would become clear ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges ). I could try to elaborate on my answer, but I am not sure I have enough time to dedicate.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, I have added a paragraph with some indication about the way to calculate the interaction. That's the best I can do in the limited time I have.

Comment: That this complex behavior is not baked in the value of $\varepsilon$ is based on an idealization for an infinite medium, or rather, a medium so large and the charges so far from its surface that the surface effect does not play a role. In most cases such a constant $\varepsilon$ will do.

Comment: @kricheli agreed.  This is what I meant in my comments.  You have expressed this much more clearly.

Comment: @GiorgioP so the formula I wrote in the question is just an approximation ??

Comment: @Ankit, it would be exact if the whole space was filled by a dielectric, or it can be considered an excellent approximation if the distance of the two charges is much larger than their distance from the boundary of the dielectric.

Comment: @GiorgioP "it can be considered an excellent approximation if the distance of the two charges is much larger than their distance from the boundary of the dielectric" --> **shouldn't the distance between the charges be lesser than the distance from the boundary to avoid boundary effects ??**

Comment: @Ankit In principle, yes. However, it is difficult to say something more without knowing the precise conditions (distances and dielectric constants).